# Does a Windows 8 boot partition have to be at the start of a drive?

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

My computer has an SSD with Windows 8 on it, and a 2TB HDD with all of my data (about half full).

My computer is randomly hanging and crashing, and I think it's because the SSD is faulty. Until I can get a replacement, I'd like to image the SSD and place it on a new partition at the end of my 2TB drive, and boot from there. However, it has occurred to me that there might be issues with booting from a different location.

Is this going to be a problem? Are there any other big problems I should look out for in trying to create and boot from a new partition at the end of a drive?

Edit: I should mention that I'm planning on using [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) to do the imaging, so any limitations of that software to accomplishing what I want to do may be relevant.

Comment: How many partitions you have? Is it partitioned using GPT or MBR partitioning?

Comment: Both drives only have 1 partition each, both NTFS

Comment: Anyways, you will have to re-install the boot loader, it can be done using system repair on Win8 dvd. But what makes you think, that the SSD is faulty?

Comment: It had exactly the same symptoms about 12 months ago. I took it to a shop and they diagnosed it as the SSD and replaced it under warranty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to my question is no, the boot partition doesn't have to be at the start of the drive. The following steps worked for me:

1. Shrunk the partition on my large drive and created a new one at the end.
2. Used DriveImage XML's drive-to-drive feature to copy my entire SSD onto the new partition.
3. Restarted my computer with the Windows 8 DVD in, and my SSD out.
4. Booted from the DVD and let it attempt to automatically 'repair' my Windows installation.
5. Restarted again, with the DVD out, and Windows 8 then did some more auto-repairing.

Everything seems to be working perfectly now, and frankly I'm pretty impressed at Windows' ability to fix itself.

Comment: You used the drive to drive feature to copy a drive to a partition? Sounds like you just cloned your ssd to a much larger drive

Comment: That's exactly what I did...